# Type Aliasing and platform switching

Tags: code-complete

I'm currently reading "Code Complete" by Steve McConnell. In section 12.9 "Creating Your Own Types (Type Aliasing)", in the pre-last paragraph of "Guidelines for Creating Your Own Types" part there are such words:

> For example, you can define a type INT32 and use it instead of *int*,
> or a type LONG64 instead of *long*. Originally, the only difference
> between the two types would be their capitalization. But when you
> moved the program to a new hardware platform, you could redefine the
> capitalized versions so that they could match the data types on the
> original hadrware.

Could you provide some examples of applying that concept when you move one hardware platform to another? I mean, it's a little bit hard to understand for me, because I haven't had any hardware experience yet. And I don't understand how to apply that concept when you move from one "platform" or "ecosystem" like Node.js to another (Java, Python, etc.).
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take the C programming language as an example.

In C, the size of the type `int` depends on the platform. On some platforms / compilers, it might be 16 bits, on others it might be 32 or 64 bits or something else.

So if you write your program for a specific platform where `int` is 32 bits, then it might not compile and run if you recompile the same source code on a different platform where `int` is 16 bits.

What the quote says, is that it might be a good idea to define, for example, `INT32` as an alias for `int`:

```
typedef int INT32;
```

And then use `INT32` everywhere in your program instead of `int`.

If you then want to compile your code on a platform where `int` is 16 bits, and for example `long` is 32 bits, then you would have to change just that one line:

```
typedef long INT32;
```

And the program would work on the new platform.

With "platform" what is meant here is hardware and/or operating system and/or compiler, not a different language (Java vs Python etc.).

Example from my own experience: Long ago I learned programming in C on the [Amiga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga). There were two C compilers you could get for it: Aztec C and Lattice C. On Aztec C, an `int` was 16 bits, while on Lattice C it was 32 bits. By using typedefs like this, you could write code that would compile the same on both compilers with minimal changes.

Comment: In fact, this idea is *such* a good idea that it was added to the C standard library, in the form of the `[u]int{fast, least, }{8, 16, 32, 64}_t` types.

Comment: It should be added that if you program in languages like Python, Java etc., this issue does not arise, because it's the interpreter/virtual machine that's *really* running your code which has that problem, and they've already solved it and hidden the difficulty from you.